# New line for some images with links and text beside each of them

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have some images which has a text and 2 links beside each of them you can see a live example at:http://developers-community.com/beta/ so I need to add some new images with text and links beside them but of course the wrapper's width won't take them in the rest of the line so I'm have trouble making a new line for new images I tried

```
<br> and <p>
```

but they didn't work here's what happens when I use`<br> and <p>` :http://jsfiddle.net/9N8Pc/1/ and when I don't this is what happens: http:// developers-community.com/beta/appsforpages.html please help me solve this, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IS this what you are looking for..See the demo..

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uN58b/1/)

```
<div style=width:100%;float:left;">

<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>

</div><br>
<div style=width:100%;float:left;">

<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes!, but can please specify what you did exactly as I find some difficulties following up what you changed :)

Comment: JUst change the images src and below two hrefs in <a> tags according to your requirement..It will work..

Comment: And by the way the Add to your page link the word "page" is not out of link, can you also fix this, sorry I took much of your time :)

Comment: IF not then add this replace this line of code..... <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:2px;">Add to your page</a></div>

Comment: Cool, I've already fixed it with width 203px but really thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited you demo and it looks like this now....[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PcFSm/)

```
    .pull - left
    {
        display: -webkit - box;
        text - align: left;
        display: inline - block;
        padding: 6px;
    }                                                                 
   .pull - left img
    {
       position: relative;
       display: block;
    }
```

Comment: This method also works but to late I've configured the other answer code, but I'm I must admit this is easier!